# Configurable map viewer search widget

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, configurable-map-viewer

I want to add search widget to my cmv application, but nothing is displayed when I click on search, I have copied and paste all the files from github in my viewer folder and I started by creating a folder called widgets then I pasted the search folder, I also pasted searchwidget.js in config folder.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You also need to include the AttributesTable widget. The Search widget will not function without it.

Comment: when i add Attrubutes Table widget, Attributes search works but spatial doesn't !!

Comment: This is not an issue I have seen before. Please submit a new question with more details including your configuration files here at stackexchange or an issue at my cmv-widgets repo at github.